label_style_number for large numbers in tblsummary
I'm using the gtsummary package to make some tabels with the tbl_summary function. In particulary, I have one that the displayed values (mean +- sd) are something like 1,234,000 +- 567,890. Is there any way to display values like 1.234e+6 +- 5.678e+5?
I have found the label_style_number function but I don't know how to use this.

You can specify any function you'd like to use in the tbl_summary(digits) argument.
library(gtsummary)

sci_fmt <- \(x) format(x, digits = 3, scientific = TRUE)
sci_fmt(1234324234)
#> [1] "1.23e+09"

trial |> 
  tbl_summary(
    include = age,
    statistic = age ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
    digits = age ~ sci_fmt
  ) |> 
  as_kable()




Characteristic
N = 200




Age
4.72e+01 (1.43e+01)


Unknown
11



Created on 2024-10-02 with reprex v2.1.1
